# C# Trouble with date picker setup at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not sure of the path to take here.  I am creating a table that lists all images from a folder location.  I need to add columns to this table for each image, one of which should be a date picker, but there is little in the way of formatting.

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("File Name");
table.Columns.Add("Receipt Date");
table.Columns[1].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
table.Columns.Add("Category");
table.Columns.Add("Amount");
table.Columns.Add("Comments");
table.Columns.Add("Attach");

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);

    table.Rows.Add(file.Name);
};

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Post your *grid* code. The `DataTable` has no UI, it's a data container. The UI is configured on the *grid*. If you want to specify that a column uses a textbox, datepicker or dropdown, you do so when specifying the grid's columns

Comment: Are you asking how to add a DateTimePicker to a DataGrid control?

Comment: BTW use `typeof(DateTime)` instead of `System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")`. Not only is it shorter, you avoid problems due to possible spelling errors

Comment: The doc page for [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8) contains an example that shows how to set it up and use different column types. This class was introduced in .NET 2.0 back in 2006, so there are *hundreds* of articles and tutorials explaining its use.

Comment: There's [an entire section for DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframework-4.8) in the Windows Forms guide. One of the articles shows [how to host a DatePicker inside a column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells)

Comment: Voting to close since this doesn't actually ask a question. Try asking again with enough detail that someone who hasn't been working on your code alongside you might be able to understand. We don't know what your code is supposed to do, what errors you're getting, what your code isn't doing, etc. Try to think of other's perspectives, we havent been working on this project with you so we don't know what you want.